# Ultrarelativistic gas and microcanonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, gas

Given the Hamiltonian of the ultrarelativstic gas $H= \sum_i^N |p_i|c$, it is known that the energy is given by $E=3Nk_BT$.
Is it possible to demonstrate this relation just by using the fact that $\phi (\lambda E) = \lambda ^{3N} \phi(E)$? ($\phi(E)$ is the total volume of the phase space).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. The starting point is the fact (Euler theorem) that if
$$
\phi(\lambda E)=\lambda^\alpha \phi(E),
$$
(homogeneity of degree $\alpha$),
we have
$$
E \phi'(E)=\alpha \phi(E).
$$
If the entropy is given by
$$
S=k_B\ln \phi,
$$
$$
\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}= \frac{k_B}{\phi} \phi'(E)=
\alpha k_B \frac{1}{E}.
$$
From here, the result follows.